# 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:InvalidRecipientsException

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office365, smtpclient

I'm trying to send ics invitation mail to multiple recipients using outlook email id. but I'm getting this error...

> Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:InvalidRecipientsException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients. InvalidRecipientsException: A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients.

Here is my code:

```
public ResponseModel SendInvite(ZoomDTO data)
{
    try
    {
        string startTime1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString())).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
        string endTime1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString())).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");

        SmtpClient sc = SmtpSettings();
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("donotreply@companyname.com", "Screen Detailing");
        if (data.TO_EMAIL.Contains(","))
        {
            string[] mailIds = data.TO_EMAIL.Split(',');
            foreach (var item in mailIds)
            {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(item));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(data.TO_EMAIL));
        }

        msg.Subject = data.SUBJECT;
        msg.Body = "Zoom URL: " + data.ZOOM_URL + "  Meeting ID: " + data.MEETING_ID + "  Zoom Password: " + data.ZOOM_PWD; //emailbody

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        //PRODID: identifier for the product that created the Calendar object
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//ABC Company//Outlook MIMEDIR//EN");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", startTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("BeginTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", endTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("EndTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION: {0}", "Location"));

        // UID should be unique.
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
        str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:Accept");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
        str.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
        ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");
        AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
        //Response.Write(str);
        // sc.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 2;
        sc.Send(msg);

        return new ResponseModel
        {
            ResultSet = "success",
            StatusCode = 1,
            StatusDescription = "Success",
            ReasonPhrase = string.Empty
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private static SmtpClient SmtpSettings()
{
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
    sc.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    sc.Port = 587;
    sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("donotreply@companyname.com", "password");
    sc.EnableSsl = true;
    return sc;
}
```

And the same code is working fine with gmail smtp settings and gmail id credentials.
Plus the same code without ics meeting invitation is working fine with office365 smtp settings and my company's id credentials which are shown in above code.

Comment: @mjwills nope, I'm sending multiple ids 'name@gmail.com, name@company.com' like this only. and it is working fine with gmail smtp settings

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I'm sending this `'name@gmail.com, name@company.com'` value in `data.TO_EMAIL` and it is totally working fine when i set gmail smtp settings. I guess the issue is not with `data.TO_EMAIL` or else I would have received this error at the first place only

Comment: If I comment out ics meeting invite part i.e. `msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);` then it's working fine. I guess something's wrong with meeting invite part

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.

These two lines should come inside `VEVENT`

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));
```

Like this:

```
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));
str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
```

Comment: I wan't to add that the organizer or one of attendees must also be the destination address

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cause is misformatted ICS.

It's very misleading but I think InvalidRecipientsException in this case is referring to the "recipients" of the ICS -- the attendees and maybe even the organizer. I had the same exact error and that's ultimately what was wrong for me. Outlook appears to strictly validate the ICS as you try to send the email, while other providers (like Gmail and SendGrid) do not.

You might try validating your ICS against a strict validator like this one: http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com/validate/

It might be that your code isn't observing the maximum line length of an ICS file: 75 characters. Your ATTENDEE lines may be exceeding that.

You might try just dropping the CN property on your attendees. It's not necessary. Although you should still be checking for the 75 character line length.